# Flask WSGI Handler FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, flask, iis, web-applications, wsgi

I am deploying a python web-app (dash, flask). I followed the tutorial in this link:
https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

This worked fine and I got the example running. Now I want to run my own application (which works fine on my local PC in debug mode). But when I deploy it similarly to the example in the link, it gives an error that a file cannot be found.

The structure of my app is as follows:

```
- main.py
- bim.py
- tools.py
   - Dictionaries
   - assets
```

When I run the app, I get the following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvxi.png)

I have no idea why the app cannot find the file, as it is in the absolute location which is provided. Hope that anyone can help me with this issue.

Additional info, packages (requirements installed):

```
Brotli==1.0.9
click==7.1.2
dash==1.15.0
dash-core-components==1.11.0
dash-html-components==1.1.0
dash-renderer==1.7.0
dash-table==4.10.0
DateTime==4.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Compress==1.5.0
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.19.1
pandas==1.1.1
plotly==4.9.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.15.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
xlrd==1.2.0
zope.interface==5.1.0
```

Permissions of Dictionary directory: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxQ9J.png)

Comment: 'Dictionaries' is in the root of the server (NOT relative to the document root). make sure this directory exists and is writeable by the user running this application.

Comment: Hi samwu, I checked permissions and the directories and the files have all permissions checked. What do you mean by NOT relative to the document root? If I move the files from Dictionaries folder to the main folder, where all my .py files are placed, I receive the same error message.

Comment: I added a new picture (see link in original post at the bottom), it does not show the error message you are referring to. And as you can see, it also shows my access to read/write is correct (I believe?) Or am i missing something?

Comment: Solved the problem. It was an error in how i genereated the abosulte path. 
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))    solved the problem